# How to pass 2 bytes string without being garbled in Groovy Script Engine?

Tags: scala, groovy, character-encoding, path, encode

Hi I'm passing path string to Groovy Script from Scala like below but when the string contains 2 bytes characters, the formatting will be garbled. How do you properly pass string to groovy script?

```
var gse = new GroovyScriptEngine()
var scriptClass = gse.loadScriptByName("script.groovy") 
var i = scriptClass.newInstance().asInstanceOf[GroovyObject]
i.setProperty("DIR_HERE", new File(".").getAbsolutePath())
 // when the path contains 2 bytes code like "c:/あああああ/bleh", 
 // the passed string will be garbled and will be like "c:/????????????/bleh"
```

Comment: What is `scriptClass.newInstance().asInstanceOf[GroovyObject]` supposed to be doing?

Comment: sorry. I forgot to put a line in the code. edited. The script itself works fine when the passed path doesn't contain 2 byte code

Comment: Ahhh, this is scala you're embedding it in isn't it?  Not Java as you said?  The scala tag got edited out 36 minutes ago because you made no mention of scala in the question.  Might be worth adding it back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I write `script.groovy` as:

```
println DIR_HERE
```

And then a new file `run.groovy` as:

```
def gse = new GroovyScriptEngine( '.' )
def scriptClass = gse.loadScriptByName("script.groovy") 
def i = scriptClass.newInstance()
i.setProperty("DIR_HERE", 'c:/あああああ/bleh' )
i.run()
```

Then when I run:

```
groovy run.groovy
```

from the command line, it prints:

```
c:/あああああ/bleh
```

Comment: Thank you. After reading this, I've done some testing and it wasn't really groovy's error. Stupid of me but it helped me track down what was wrong anyway..